# Interchange columns using bash

Tags: shell

I have a file containing two columns e.g.

- 10 25
- 26 38
- 40 62
- 85 65
- 88 96
- 97 8

I want first column to contain all minimum values and second column containing all maximum values. Something like this:

- 10 25
- 26 38
- 40 62
- 65 85
- 88 96
- 8 97

Comment: You have 3 scripting options tagged, yet you have no code. Are you asking which scripting option to use? Or are you asking someone to do this for you?

Comment: Someone who can do it using shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
awk '{
if ($2 < $1 )
  print $2," "$1;
else
  print $1," "$2;
}' filename.txt
```

Make sure columns are space separated

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, it is straightforward:

```
values = [
    (10, 25),
    (26, 38),
    (40, 62),
    (85, 65),
    (88, 96),
    (97, 8),
]

result = [(min(v), max(v)) for v in values]
```

You get:

```
[(10, 25), (26, 38), (40, 62), (65, 85), (88, 96), (8, 97)]
```

Using bash… I don't know:

```
python -c "<your command here>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter a file name > "
read name

if ["$1" -gt "$2"];
then 
awk ' {  t= $1; $1 = $2; $2=t ; print; } ' $name
fi
exit 0;
```